# 3D java library

Tags: java-3d

as a beginner, I've tried to use java to make a 2D object.
then I want to make a 3D object but in the editor application that I use does not support Java 3D libraries. roughly, how I could incorporate 3D java libraries into the application that I use.
I use the "jcreator" and "bluej" as java editor.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't come with any 3D libraries built in, so you're going to have to download and install one yourself. You can get the Java 3D API [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html). [Here's](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/) a rough tutorial to take a look at as well, [this](http://www.java3d.org/) may help too. Just as a heads up, there is far more math involved in 3D programming than there is with 2D. Make sure you have a solid grasp on how 2D graphics work before you jump in to 3D. Good luck, have fun.

Also, if you're looking into creating games in Java then I would suggest [lwjgl](http://lwjgl.org/) (Lightweight Java Game Library).